# Larger dictionary items to HTML table format: Performance Improvements

Tags: python, python-2.7, performance, webapp2

We iterating through almost 20,000 dictionary items and converting that to an HTML table format.

`master_data` contains 20,000 dictionary items and more items will be added each day.

`headers` contains the all the possible 72 keys of items in the `master_data` dict.(Excluding 'ID').

There are a few possibilities that not all the keys in `headers` will not exist in the `master_data` items.

The below code takes almost 50 Sec to complete iteration and print it as HTML table. I'm curious to know if there is any better way to improve the performance.

```
master_data = {
    '00000': {'ID': 'A0', 'Head1': 'V1', 'Head2': 'V2', 'Head3': 'V3', ...., 'Head72': 'V72'},
    '00001': {'ID': 'A1', 'Head1': 'V1', 'Head2': 'V2', 'Head3': 'V3', ...., 'Head72': 'V72'},
    '00002': {'ID': 'A2', 'Head1': 'V1', 'Head4': 'V4', 'Head5': 'V5', ...., 'Head70': 'V70'},
    '00003': {'ID': 'A3', 'Head1': 'V1', 'Head2': 'V2', 'Head4': 'V4', ...., 'Head72': 'V72'},
    .....
    .....
    .....
    '19075': {'ID': 'ZZZ122', 'Head1': 'V1', 'Head2': 'V2', 'Head3': 'V3', ...., 'Head72': 'V72'},
}
headers = ['Head1', 'Head2', 'Head3'...., 'Head72']

self.response.out.write("<html><body><table><tr>")
for header in headers:
    self.response.out.write('<td>%s</td>' % header)
self.response.out.write('</tr>')

for key, data in master_data.iteritems():
    data['ID'] = '=HYPERLINK("{0}/{1}","{2}")'.format(
        self.request.host_url, data.get('id'), data.get('ID')
    )

    self.response.out.write("<tr>")
    for header in headers:
        self.response.out.write('<td>%s</td>' % data.get(header, ''))
    self.response.out.write("</tr>")

self.response.out.write('</table></body></html>')
```

Due to some platform dependency, I can't use `pandas`.

Answer (score 2):

Do not call self.response.out.write multiple times. This makes your code so laggy. 
Create new string and append html code to it:

```
html = ""
html+= "<html><body><table><tr>"
...
self.response.out.write(html)
```

Answer (score 2):

While @Nuts's answer gives you the major performance boost, you can save a bit more time by doing the list comprehension (10-15% speed boost):

```
result_strs = []
for key, data in master_data.items():
    result_strs += ['<td>%s</td>' % data.get(header, '') for header in headers]
```

You can go further and try this (2x times faster than original):

```
result_strs = []
for key, data in master_data.items():
    s = '</td><td>'.join(data.get(header, '') for header in headers)
    s = ''.join(('<td>', s, '</td>'))
    result_strs.append(s)
```

Notice though that resulting data structures are insignificantly different.